# <Android> Toolbar not displaying

Tags: android, toolbar, appcompatactivity

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".main_drawer">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
         android:background="@color/octo"/>

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="am.octogr.app.octocopy.NavigationDrawerFragment"

        tools:layout="@layout/main_drawer_listview" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Hi, how can I put a Toolbar within this layout?
This layout for Navigation Drawer.
I've tried some code but still not working.
1. Under FrameLayout: Toolbar did not appear.
2. Below FrameLayout: Toolbar appear but content did not display.
3. Have DrawerLayout in a LinearLayout but my fragment seems didn't work well.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to explain.

Android draws `View`s from top to down so; **A**-**B**-**C**- are you 3 respective Views in your `DrawerLayout`. now A being the `Toolbar` is drawn first with params `width` fit-to-the-overallwidth and `height` fit the content itself, B is drawn with `width` fit-to-the-overallwidth and `height` fit-to-the-overallheight, etc etc. that means your FrameLayout is drawn second in the drawing successions and on top of your `Toolbar` but since its covered you do not see that it is there, if you bring it below, your Toolbar is drawn second in succession hence you see it.

i hope you can deduct a solution from it now.

Answer (score 0):

Have the toolbar in another layout which would be your main content view

```
 <!-- The main content view -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/toolbar"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
             android:background="@color/octo"/>

        <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
             space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".main_drawer">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="am.octogr.app.octocopy.NavigationDrawerFragment"

        tools:layout="@layout/main_drawer_listview" />

        <!-- Your Content -->

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

with a separate **tool_bar.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/octo"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Don't forget to **Initialize** your Toolbar and set it as the ActionBar:

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

With a **minSdkVersion of 14**

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works fine for me.

Use this XML for your drawer activity.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_layout" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.rsa.myapplication.DrawerActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/> <!--This line is important-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find recent documentation about it on [appbar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index). 
They missed to include some code to make it work, here they are :

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

where R.menu.menu is your xml file in your project's res/menu/ directory. Paste above code on your activity which implement the Toolbar.